# How is the mahalanobis distance like the euclidean distance?

Tags: distance, multivariate-normal-distribution

Let's say $\vec{x}$ is an $n$ dimensional observation, $\vec{\mu}$ the $n$ dimensional mean of the sample that $\vec{x}$ is from and $\Sigma$ the $n \times n$ covariance matrix of that sample.

Then the mahalanobis distance is defined like this
$$
mahal(\vec{x}) = \sqrt{(\vec{x} - \vec{\mu})^T \Sigma^{-1} (\vec{x} - \vec{\mu})}
$$
Intuitively this function does this

1. Center $\vec{x}$ around the mean $\vec{\mu}$
2. "Remove" the covariance and variance integral to $\vec{x}$ with $\Sigma^{-1}$
3. Compute dot product between the left $(\vec{x} - \vec{\mu})$ and the right **transformed** $(\vec{x} - \vec{\mu})$
4. Compute the square root of the dot product from 3. which amounts to the euclidean distance

The problem I see is that it only "removes" the covariance from the right $(\vec{x} - \vec{\mu})$ but not the left. Which means that this isn't the euclidean distance in the space with base $\Sigma$ since the left hand side didn't change base to $\Sigma$ like the right hand side.

As I see it the the mahalanobis distance would have to be defined like this for it to be like the euclidean distance
$$
mahal'(\vec{x}) = \sqrt{(\Sigma^{-1} (\vec{x} - \vec{\mu}))^T (\Sigma^{-1} (\vec{x} - \vec{\mu}))}
$$

I also tried to decompose $\Sigma = E \Lambda E^{-1}$ where $E$ are eigenvectors of $\Sigma$ and $\Lambda$ its eigenvalues. Then the mahalanobis distance could be written like
$$
\begin{align}
mahal(\vec{x}) &= \sqrt{(\vec{x} - \vec{\mu})^T \Sigma^{-1} (\vec{x} - \vec{\mu})} \\ &= \sqrt{(E^{-1} (\vec{x} - \vec{\mu}))^T \Lambda^{-1} (E^{-1} (\vec{x} - \vec{\mu}))}
\end{align}
$$
This fits my intuition of euclidean distance much more, except the right hand side is scaled by $\Lambda^{-1}$ which makes it not the same as euclidean distance.

Comment: How would you rewrite the diagonal matrix $\Lambda ^{-1}$ so that $z^\top \Lambda^{-1} z$ has the same rescaling applied to both $z^\top$ and $z$? That is, how can you rewrite this so that there is some matrix $A$ such that $z^\top A A z$?

Comment: You could define $A$ as a diagonal matrix with entries $\sqrt{1 / \lambda_i}$, then $AA = \Lambda^{-1}$. This would also mean that we could transform $z^\top \Lambda^{-1}  z = (A z)^\top (A z)$ and have both $z$ scaled by the standard deviation $1/\sqrt{\lambda}$?

Comment: Yes; $\Lambda ^{-1} = \Lambda ^{-\frac{1}{2}}\Lambda ^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. So if we replace $z$ with appropriate expressions from your derivation, we end up with the inner product of two vectors under a square root.